# MinGW vs TDM-GCC-64: post increment execution

Tags: linux, visual-studio, gcc, post-increment

I have below code snippet.

```
int main()
{
    int j = 10;
    printf("%d %d %d", j++, j++, j++);
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio 2019 output (on windows): `10 10 10`
Gcc output (on Linux): `12 11 10`

Why this difference in output?

Comment: The order of evaluation of function arguments is implementation-specific and/or undefined behaviour. Looking for a duplicate ...

Comment: See [sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4176333/1983398).